# CSS and Image not showing in rendered pdf using html-pdf-node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, npm

I am trying to generate html to pdf in **Node.js** using [html-pdf-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node) package. The page is working fine if I open the html file in the browser but when I generate it to pdf using html-pdf-node, the images and the css is not rendered in the pdf.

Here is my code:

**template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="../images/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Logo image">
  </div>
  

  <div class="container align-items-center atd-title text-center">
    <h3>Title Here</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container align-items-center atd-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>Sir:</p>
        <p class="atd-paragraph">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**service.js**

```
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
let ejs = require('ejs');
let html_to_pdf = require('html-pdf-node');

// Read HTML Template
let template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../path/to/template.html"), 'utf8');
                
let html = ejs.render(template, {name: "test"});
let options = { format: 'A4' };
let file = { content: html };
let pdf = await html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options);
return pdf;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the HTML string is being passed to `html-pdf-node`, the other assets like images and CSS are not. `html-pdf-node` uses [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) as a headless browser to render the web page before saving it as PDF, when it tries to resolve the assets it sends HTTP requests that just fail.

You have two options to solve this:

- Create a standalone HTML file with inline CSS and images as data URLs
- Open a web server so that the assets can be resolved without being embedded

The simplest option is the second one, here is a minimal example:

```
const express = require('express')
const html_to_pdf = require('html-pdf-node')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./index.html"), 'utf8')
const content = ejs.render(template, { title: "Awesome title!" })
fs.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"), content, () => {
    app.use(express.static('src/public'))

    const server = app.listen(port, async () => {
        const url = `http://localhost:${port}`
        const options = { format: 'A4', path: 'output.pdf' }
        const file = { url }
        await html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options)

        server.close()
    })
})
```

I've created a working project here: https://github.com/Guerric-P/html-pdf-node-demo

Comment: is it possible even if we use ejs template engine ?

Comment: Well yes you could add an ejs compilation step in the process. Do you want me to provide the code?

Comment: i need a sample code for html string instead of url, do you have one ?

Comment: the OP used `let file = { content: html };`, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it's possible there is to find the right tooling (probably something like webpack with the right plugins)

Comment: could you provide using ejs template ?

Comment: Can you precise do you want HTML? If so, why? Or do you just want ejs templating?

Comment: my apologize, i want a sample code for ejs templating.

Comment: I've updated my answer and the GitHub repository

Comment: Does your CSS background color works?

Comment: I downloaded the project, and installed all the necessary modules, but I get a pdf file with the content ; Cannot GET /

Comment: @mEHNImOHAMED do not `cd` to `src`. Stay in the root folder then run the project with `node .`

Comment: @Guerric P I fixed the problem and the CSS was applied actually except the ::before that was not applied, and I don't know why

Comment: Thanks men, You saved my 3 days of work, I spent all 3 days to solve this image not rendering issue and tried many solutions but no one will be right. and When I try this, It give me success. Thanks men

Answer (score 2):

```html
<style>
      html { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }
</style>
```

Add this into the headers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).